# UTC time conversion: How do I convert an integer (UTC) into a 'datetime' time stamp?

Tags: swift, timestamp

Simple question:
How do I convert an integer in UTC to standard 'datetime' to a local 'time stamp'?
The following is a time-stamp source in UTC:

```
"risetime": 1516588843
```

Comment: A quick look at the documentation for `Date` would have answered your question.

Comment: Just did, only question is which initializer?   I'm assuming: let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: secs)

Comment: Yes. See the duplicate linked at the top of your question.